# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'DT_RowId')

Tags: laravel, datatable

I am new to Laravel and Datatable and working on home project.
Actually Trying to get the data from ajax and load in to the data table. But getting error "jquery.dataTables.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'DT_RowId')"

```
<table id="milksalemonthwise" class="table table-bordered table-hover table dataTables_filter table-striped cell-border" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="text-center">Date</th>
            <th class="text-center">Buffalo</th>
            <th class="text-center">A2</th>
            <th class="text-center">Jersey</th>
            <th class="text-center">Total</th>
          </tr>

          <tbody>

          </tbody>
        </thead>
      </table>
```

ajax code

```
var table = $('#milksalemonthwise').DataTable();

            $.ajax({

              type: 'get',
              url: '/getmilksaleformonth',
              dataType: "json",
              data: {
                      getmonthnameforajax: getmonthnameforajax,
                    },

              success: function(milksellcurrentfortable) {

                  //alert(milksellcurrentfortable);

                  var result = jQuery(milksellcurrentfortable);

                  //alert(result);

                  $('#milksalemonthwise').DataTable( {

                    processing: false,
                    serverside: true,
                    destroy: true,
                    "data": result.data,
                    "ajax": {
                              "url": result
                            },
                    "columns" : [
                            {"data": "month_name"},
                            {"data": "buffalo"},
                            {"data": "a2"},
                            {"data": "jersey"},
                            {"data": "total"}
                      ]
                });



              }


            });
```

Thanks in advance